# In TypeScript with jQuery, why do I get the error 'this' implicitly has type any

Tags: jquery, typescript

My code is as follows:

```
$(function() {

    $("table").on("click", function() {
      const button = $(this);
    });

});
```

My error is:

this implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.

How do I fix this error?

Edit:

My tsconfig.json is as follows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "node_modules/*",
                "src/types/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Edit 2:

I have the following in my package.json

```
"@types/jquery": "^2.0.41",
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce that error. What version of TypeScript are you using? Do you have `noImplicitAny: true` in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Yes, question edited.

Comment: Did you install jQuery types? e.g. `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery`

Comment: Yes, please see edit 2 above

Comment: Hm, the current version of the jquery types is 3.3.5, try upgrading?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Have upgraded to     "@types/jquery": "^3.3.5", but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is pretty much exactly what the compiler says:

```
error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.

4         const button = $(this);
                           ~~~~
```

That's because you have `strict: true` set in your `tsconfig.json`, which also turns on `noImplicitThis`. TypeScript's [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) state that `noImplicitThis` means:

> Raise error on this expressions with an implied `any` type.

And since you're not specifying the type of `this` before using it in your event handler, you get an error.

The fix is to specify the type of `this`:

```
$(function() {

    $("table").on("click", function(this: HTMLButtonElement) {
      const button = $(this);
    });

});
```

That will tell TypeScript what the intended type of `this` is in your event handler.

Alternatively, you could change `strict` to `false` in your `tsconfig.json`, but that may not be a viable option.

Comment: For anyone else confused about specifying `this` as a function parameter, it is explained in the TS docs here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters